# Unable to set custom data in show action field in symfony sonata admin

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony3.x

I have a show page and I want to add a custom value.

I have tried doing what I did in other actions which is to add an array to the
 third parameter with the data key like so:

```
protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
{
    $showMapper
        ->add('name')                      
        ->add('dateEnd')
        ->add('example', null,
            array('data' => 'example value')
        )
    ;
}
```

In the configureListFields action, this works. I have injected custom values with the data attribute.

But still I am not able to access key example in the `show.html.twig` file.
It gives me this error

> Variable "example" does not exist.

What should I do to access this custom variable in the twig file ?

Comment: Show us this `show.html.twig` file too

Comment: i use 3.2.13 version of symphony

Comment: in show.html.twig file i use below normal variable access code:                           {{example}}

Comment: please suggest me why it give me error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
{{ elements.elements.example.options.data }}
```

in your twig template

Answer (score 1):

I used this solution. In the `configureShowFields()` method of an Admin class:

```
$showMapper
        ->with('Tab Name')
        ->add(
            'any_name',
            null,
            [
                'template' => 'Admin/Custom/any_name_show_template.html.twig',
                'customData' => $this->someRepository->getSomeEntityBy($field),
                'anotherCustomData' => $this->someService->getSomeDataBy($value),
            ]
        )
    ;
```

In the custom template, you can access custom data by `field_description.options.<customFieldName>`, so for provided example data accessors would be `{{ field_description.options.customData }}` and `{{  field_description.options.anotherCustomData }}`

For the shorter field name in the Twig template, you can do like this:

```
{% set customData = field_description.options.customData %}
```

and access the custom data like `{{ customData }}`

Hope this helps and saves time.